# Iteration on a stream

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate my variable threads :

```
threads: Subject<{[key: string]: Thread }> = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

Despite my numerous attempts:

```
return this.threads.asObservable().map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
  for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
    console.log("key", threadDictionary[key]);
    if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
      return threadDictionary[key];
    }
  }
});


return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
.flatMap((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
    for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
      console.log("key", threadDictionary[key]);
      if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
        return threadDictionary[key];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

/////////////////////
EDIT
/////////////////////

```
return this.threads.asObservable().map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
  return threadDictionary[key];
});

  for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
    console.log("key", threadDictionary[key]);
    if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
      return threadDictionary[key];
    }
  }
```

I would like to know if this is possible to create a For loop on my variable threads. Should I change its type of variable? Or how to make this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate over the `threadDictionary` argument as it is not an array. You could try return the value from calling `.map()` and then iterating over the result.

```
var threadDictionary = this.threads.asObservable().map((threadDictionary: {[key: string]: Thread}) => {
  return threadDictionary;
});

for( let key in threadDictionary ) {
  console.log("key", threadDictionary[key]);
  if(threadDictionary[key].participants[0].name.startsWith(str)) {
    return threadDictionary[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your solution.
I have published my post but I do not think it is like this ..

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: see the example I just provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried but it does not work...
Why do I return 'false' when I display `threadDictionary [key]` in the console?
Normally this should be a value, right?